# Does non-symmetric positive definite matrix have positive eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I found out that there exist positive definite matrices that are non-symmetric, and I know that symmetric positive definite matrices have positive eigenvalues.

Does this hold for non-symmetric matrices as well?

Comment: Caution: there is no general agreement on what "positive definite" means for non-Hermitian matrices.  Which definition are you using?

Comment: How about:
$$[x\ y]\left[\matrix{1&1\cr -1&1}\right]\left[\matrix{x \cr y}\right]=[x\ y]\left[\matrix {x+y\cr-x+y}\right]=(x^2+xy)+(-xy+y^2)=x^2+y^2,$$
and
$$
\left|\matrix {1-\lambda &1\cr -1&1-\lambda } \right| =(1-\lambda)^2+1\ne 0.
$$

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: positive-definite should not be a term that applies to matrices. It should only apply to _quadratic forms_, which are naturally described by _symmetric_ matrices only.

Comment: It's a nice sentiment, but the genie's out of the bottle.

Comment: There is a nice explanation about non-hermitian positive definite matrices. Please have a look into http://www.math.technion.ac.il/iic/ela/ela-articles/articles/vol20_pp621-639.pdf

Answer (score 74):

Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be any non-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix but "positive definite" in the sense that:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \ne 0 \implies x^T A x > 0$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ need not be positive. For an example, the matrix in David's comment:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

has eigenvalue $1 \pm i$. However, the real part of any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is always positive.

Let $\lambda = \mu + i\nu\in\mathbb C $ where $\mu, \nu \in \mathbb{R}$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Let $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be a right eigenvector associated with $\lambda$. Decompose $z$ as $x + iy$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$$(A - \lambda) z = 0 \implies \left((A - \mu) - i\nu\right)(x + iy) = 0
\implies \begin{cases}(A-\mu) x + \nu y = 0\\(A - \mu) y - \nu x = 0\end{cases}$$
This implies

$$x^T(A-\mu)x + y^T(A-\mu)y = \nu (y^T x - x^T y) = 0$$

and hence
$$\mu = \frac{x^TA x + y^TAy}{x^Tx + y^Ty} > 0$$

In particular, this means any real eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is positive.

Comment: Is the converse true?  If all of the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ have positive real parts, does this mean that $x^TAx > 0$ for any $x \ne 0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$?  What if we assume $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @nukeguy The converse is false. example $A = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 7\\1 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Can we put an extra condition (perhaps a bound on the off-diagonal entries in terms of the diagonal entries?) that in addition to a positive spectrum guarantees positivity of the matrix?

Comment: @achillehui Nice answer, and upvoted: Does the counter example matrix you gave above have a square root?

Comment: @Mathmath, yes, $A$ do have square roots, e.g.  $ \frac{\sqrt{2}I_2+A}{\sqrt{6 + 2\sqrt{2}}}$ is one such square root.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks a lot, let me check the calculation on my own.

Comment: The =0 part in the equation after "This implies" just comes from the fact that the dot product of x and y (which is a scalar) is equal to its transpose...

Answer (score 10):

I am answering the first part of @nukeguy's comment, who asked:

> Is the converse true? If all of the eigenvalues of a matrix $$ have
> positive real parts, does this mean that $^>0$ for any
> $≠0∈ℝ^$? What if we assume $$ is diagonalizable?

I have a counterexample, where $A$ has positive eigenvalues, but it is not positive definite:
$    A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
        7   & -2 & -4  \\
        -17 & 40 & -19 \\
        -21 & -9 & 31
    \end{bmatrix}
$. Eigenvalues of this matrix are  $1.2253$, $27.4483$, and $49.3263$, but it indefinite because if $x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-48 & -10& -37\end{bmatrix}$ and $x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-48 &10 &-37\end{bmatrix}$, then we have $_1_1^T = -1313$ and $_2_2^T = 37647.$