# If $A$ is positive definite then so is $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know how to show the inverse of positive definite is positive definite but I don't know how to expand that.

Suppose $A$ is positive definite then $A$ is invertible, so define $y=Ax$ for $x\neq 0$. Then
$y^TA^{-1}y=x^TA^TA^{-1}Ax=x^TAx>0$, so the inverse of $A$ is positive definite.

How can I show that for other powers of $A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to prove this is through  eigenvalues. Since $A$ is positive definite, it is a symmetric matrix. 
$$A \text{ is positive definite } \iff \text{ all eigenvalues are positive. }$$

It is known that for any matrix $M$:
$$\lambda \text{ eigenvalue of matrix } M \implies \lambda^k \text{ eigenvalue of matrix } M^k,\quad k=1,2,\ldots$$

Also, you can use the fact that for any invertible matrix $M$: $$\lambda \text{ eigenvalue of matrix } M \implies \dfrac 1{\lambda^k} \text{ eigenvalue of matrix } M^{-k}, \quad k = 1,2,\ldots$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Comment: @shimura You are welcome!

Comment: @thanasissdr matrix A may not be symmetric,what would you say in case A is not symmetric?

Comment: @Ibs By definition a positive definite matrix is symmetric.

Comment: @thanasissdr it may be convention of different books,I have studied definition which says that A is positive definite if x'Ax >0 for all x (x' being transpose of X)

Comment: @Ibs Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues)  could be a bit more insightful.

Comment: @Ibs Or even [this](http://web.mit.edu/14.102/www/notes/posdef.pdf).