# What are the possible methods of quadratic cost minimization within the unit $n$-cube?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

Before you read this, please understand I'm not a specialist in optimization so I may be ignorant of many well-known results in that field.

I am interested in hearing about methods for minimizing the quadratic cost $L(u) = u^{tr}Mu$, where $u \in R^n$ and $M$ is an $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix, subject to the constraint $0 < \sum_{i=1}^n|u_i| \leq 1$.

I have a feeling some form of dynamic programming can do this, but I would need to be pointed to some relevant literature.

**Edit:** I think this is phrased poorly and most people who tried to help are confused. I have tried deleting it and trying again, but it won't allow me to delete due to there being an answer.

While I was not deliberately trying to redefine the problem after someone answered--$u = 0$ is just not reasonable given the application--trying to make myself clear made it turn out that way.

I also don't think the problem I *want* to communicate is unsolvable; that would again be unreasonable, so I must have screwed up. I am just going to abandon this failure to launch and try again.

Comment: By $M\ge0$ do you mean all entries in the matrix are $\ge0$ or that $M$  is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @kimchilover $M$ is positive semidefinite. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Okay, I'll bite.  Is $M$ symmetric?

Comment: @hardmath In general no. Actually, $L(u) = (v - Au)^{tr}M(v - Au)$, $v\in R^n$, $A\in R^{n\times n}$ would probably be a better generalized form of $L(u)$. Basically, I'm looking for methods of incorporating the constraint of restricting the vector to the unit $n$-cube into a traditional least-squares optimization.

Comment: Two points to consider before reposting (or perhaps editing the current problem, which I'd consider reasonable in the circumstances).  First, you should identify what conditions in the application guarantee that $u\neq 0$.  Simply imposing that by itself doesn't allow us to minimize the quadratic cost $u^T M u$, but if the application naturally requires (say) $Au=v$ for some known nonzero right hand side $v$, then seeking a minimum makes sense.

Comment: Second, you should explain the properties of $M$ more carefully.  There isn't a standard notion of what it should mean for $M$ to be positive definite or semi-definite unless $M$ is *symmetric*.  See this [previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues) for discussion and examples.

Comment: @hardmath both your suggestions are taken to heart and incorporated in to the repost at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401911/least-squares-minimization-subject-to-the-constraint-sum-ju-j-leq-1?noredirect=1#comment4958090_2401911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A meta answer:

Have you read the Wikipedia article about [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming)? It, and the references it points to, give an overview that might be hard to get from this forum.  I have several comments: (1) this is a highly technical and active area of research, so sorting out the landscape is hard, (2) very often practicalities like availability of this or that software package determine your algorithm choice, and (3) each piece of software for convex minimization seems to expect problems to be presented in a slightly different format, which may or may not cause headaches for you.

As an instance of this last point:  in your problem statement you use the word *cube* to describe your feasible set, but in the body of your post you use the formula $\sum_i |u_i|\le 1$ which does *not* cut out a cube.  This matters because a cube in $n$ dimensions is cut out by $2n$ linear inequalities and your figure is cut out by $2^n$ linear inequalities.  So any software that demands linear inequality constraints poses a problem for you, if say $n>20$.  A fix is to note that figure has only $2n$ vertices, so your feasible points can be represented as convex combinations of vertices, by parameterizing by a $2n+1$-simplex. I offer this not as a recommendation for what to do, but rather as an instance of what kinds of headaches and what kinds of headache-avoiding shifts might be ahead for you.

My advice, if the problem you posed is of importance to you: make friends with a numerical analyst or minimization expert, and be guided by what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Before the OP redefined the problem:
Well, I think $u=0$ solves your minimization problem.

After the OP redefined the problem:
Let $C$ denote the set of constraint-obeying $u$ vectors.
We have $\inf_{u\in C} L(u) = 0$ but the  value $0$ is not attained by any $u\in C$.  That is, there is a sequence of $u^{(k)}\in C$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} L( u^{(k)}) = 0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} u^{(k)} = 0.$
The set $C$ is open; its closure $\overline C$ contains $u=0$, which minimizes $L$ on $\overline C$.

By the way, the set cut out by the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n|u_i|\le1$ is not a cube but some kind of higher-dimensional octohedron. Putting in $0\le \dots$ simply removes the $0$ point.

Comment: $u = 0$ is a meaningless solution in the application this comes from, so you can revise the condition to $M$ being strictly positive definite if this enables a more realistic solution. The true form of $M$ is going to be time varying, but we need only consider a single step.

Comment: You said $M$ is positive semidefinite. That implies $L(u)\ge0$ no matter what $u$ is.  Since $u=0$ obeys your constraints, we know $u$ is the absolute minimizer of $L$ on your constraint set.  Maybe you meant to ask a different question, but I answered the one you asked.

Comment: Perhaps then I phrased the question wrong. I have added an additional part to the constraint that precludes the trivial solution.

Comment: The modification you made makes it impossible to achieve the minimum.