# Least squares minimization subject to the constraint $\sum_j|u_j| \leq 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

I would like to learn about methods for minimizing the cost $L(u) = (f - Au)^{tr}M(f-Au)$, where $f \in R^m$ is a known vector, $u \in R^n$ is the argument of the minimization and $A \in R^{n\times m}$, $M \in R^{n\times n}$, subject to the constraint $\sum_j |u_j| \leq 1$.

Comment: How big are $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Is $M$ known to be positive semidefinite, or could it be indefinite?

Comment: If $M$ is not necessarily positive semidefinite, but the dimension $n$ is small ($\leq 5$), it can be solved analytically quite quickly.

If $M$ is positive semidefinite, the problem is a convex optimization problem, and you have a large variety of methods to solve it. Suggesting a method blindly without understanding, for example, what are the order of magnitude of $m$ and $n$ will lead nowhere.

Comment: @Alex $m$ and $n$ are different in different specific instances. It would be an improvement to know about *any* methods--I'm curious about the analytic method you speak of for instance--but generally I am unable to provide specific order information other than $n$ and $m$ are probably between the one and four digits.

Comment: @BrianBorchers positive semidefinite makes sense to me (ensures that the minimum cost is zero), but you can take indefinite if this leads to a reasonable method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint $\sum_{j} | u_{j} | \leq 1$ is easy to convert to a system of linear inequalities.  Introduce auxilliary variables $t_{j}$, $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$.  Then add the constraints

$u_{j} \leq t_{j} $ for $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$-u_{j} \leq t_{j} $ for $j=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$\sum t_{j} \leq 1$.

This is a very standard problem transformation described in many textbooks on optimization.

The more important issue here is whether $A^{T}MA$ is positive semidefinite or indefinite.

If this matrix is indefinite, then you have a nonconvex linearly constrained quadratic optimization problem which can be hard to solve to optimality even for relatively small values of $n$ (e.g. it could be hard to solve for values $n$ in the thousands.)  Typically, branch and bound algorithms using a convex underestimator are used to solve problems like this.

If the matrix is positive semidefinite, then you have convex linearly constrained quadratic optimization problem which should be relatively easy to solve even if $n$ is in the hundreds of thousands or millions.  For relatively small values of $m$ and $n$, an active set method would be appropriate.  For very large values of $m$ and $n$ (hundreds of thousands to millions), some kind of first order method would be best.  In particular, since projecting onto the one-norm unit ball is easy, you might consider using a projected gradient method.

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned I am *not* an expert on optimization, so all of this info is new. This sort of advice is exactly what I wanted.