# Analyze the symmetric property of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

In the definition, a positive definite matrix is usually referred to symmetric expressed in quadratic form.

1. So I am confused about is it always symmetric?
2. Why do they refer to the symmetric property in its definition?
3. Please give me some examples and proof of this problem.

Comment: A proof of *what*? That it is symmetric? Or that its eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: Let quadratic form $f$ be defined by 

$$f (\mathrm x) := \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Since $\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$ is a *scalar*, then $(\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x)^\top = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$, i.e., $\mathrm x^\top \mathrm A^\top \mathrm x = \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x$. Hence,

$$\mathrm x^\top \left(\frac{\mathrm A - \mathrm A^\top}{2}\right) \mathrm x = 0$$

Thus, the **skew-symmetric** part of matrix $\mathrm A$ does not contribute anything to the quadratic form.

Comment: Please, define positive definiteness. AFAIK matrices are not positive definite, quadratic forms are.

Comment: @Miguel I think it's a little pedantic to make that distinction when this page exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Comment: @N8tron Well, that is the whole point of the OP: definite positiveness only makes sense for **symmetric** matrices, which can be identified with quadratic forms.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most authors define positive definite matrices as a subclass of symmetric matrices. This is not necessary, but then the usually equivalent definitions of positive definite matrices diverge.

---

**Positive definite matrices by inner products**

If you consider $\langle v, A v\rangle> 0,\forall v\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ as the defining property, then consider a matrix $A=S+T$, where $S$ is symmetric and positive definite (no definition problem because symmetric), and $T$ is a non-zero [skew-symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix), i.e. $T^\top=-T$. Then $A$ is not symmetric, but positive definite because

$$\def\<{\langle} \def\>{\rangle}\< v, A v\>=\<v,(S+T)v\>=\underbrace{\<v,Sv\>}_{>\, 0}+\underbrace{\<v,Tv\>}_{=\,0}> 0,\qquad\text{for all $v\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$}.$$

Note that $\<v,Tv\>=0$ because $\<v,Tv\>=\<T^\top v,v\>=\<-Tv,v\>=-\<v,Tv\>$.

**Example**. Take the positive definite identity matrix $I$ and the skew-symmetric matrix

$$S=\begin{pmatrix} \phantom+0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

From this we obtain the positive definite but not symmetric matrix

$$A=I+S=\begin{pmatrix} \phantom+1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

However, the eigenvalues are no longer real (they are $1\pm i$), hence no longer positive in the usual sense. They are however still located on the positive half-plane. Anyway, non-real eigenvalues are not a problem for the defining property, as we have $\<v,Av\>=v_1^2+v_2^2> 0$.

---

**Positive definite matrices by eigenvalues**

If you define positive definite matrix by having positive eigenvalues only, then there are also non-symmetric examples. E.g. take

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} \phantom+1 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

which is not symmetric, but has positive eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ only.

You can find more such matrices in the following ways:

- **Method 1**. Choose a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of $\Bbb R^n$, but no orthogonal basis. In the above example I chose $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Then choose $n$ different eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n> 0$. Let $V=(v_1,...,v_n)^\top$ be the matrix with the $v_i$ as its *rows*, and $D=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$. Then the matrix
  $$A=VDV^{-1}$$
  is non-symmetric and has only positive eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. That it is not be symmetric can be seen as follows: the $v_i$ will be the eigenvectors of your matrix $A$. But symmetric matrices will have an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors, while our matrix will not (because we have chosen them this way). So it cannot be symmetric.
- **Method 2**. Choose a non-diagonal [upper/lower triangluar matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) (only non-zero values above/below the diagonal). If you put only positive values on the diagonal, then this matrix will have only positive eigenvalues (as these are exactly the values on the diagonal), but it is obviously not symmetric. By putting sufficiently large values off-diagonal, we can have positive eigenvalues, while not satisfying  $\<v,Av\>>0$ for all $v\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$. Choose e.g.
  $$A=\begin{pmatrix} \phantom{+10}1 & 0 \\ -100 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
  This matrix has again eigenvalues $1$ and $2$, but $\<v,Av\>=v_1^2+2v_2^2-100v_1v_2$, hence $v=(1,1)$ gives $\<v,Av\>=-97<0$.

Comment: Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: @greenworld Counterexample to what? A positive semi-definite non-symmetric matrix? A symmetric but indefinite matrix?

Comment: It is a positive definite matrix but it is not symmetric. By the way, can you explain why do they mention about its symmetric property in the definition? Why do they not give a general definition for all case?

Comment: @greenworld Like this one?

Comment: Yes, how about my last question of the previous comment?

Comment: @greenworld I am pretty sure there are authors that do this for general matrices, it depends on what you are going to do with them and if you need this generality. Where do you came about this definition? The first encounter is usually to define inner products $\<v,w\>_A:=v^\top A w$. Because these products should be symmetric $\<v,w\>=\<w,v\>$ (the angle between a vector $v$ and $w$ is the same as between $w$ and $v$) they restrict to symmetric matrices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78731/discussion-between-greenworld-and-m-winter).

Comment: It's kind of overdramatic to say "the eigenvalues are no longer positive, not even real"... they're as positive (i.e. in the right half-plane) as you could possibly expect a number in the complex plane to be. That last counterexample is quite a gem though. +1

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks for this remark. I have not looked at it from this angle. I might include this in my answer when I have time.

Answer (score 15):

Recall that any matrix can be expressed as the sum of a symmetric part and a skew part as follow

$$A=\overbrace{\frac12(A+A^T)}^{symmetric}+\overbrace{\frac12(A-A^T)}^{skew}$$

and since the quadratic form for the skew part is equal to $0$ we have that  the positive definiteness depends solely upon the symmetric part.

Comment: My question is for a general case when we do not consider quadratic form. Can we say that a positive definite matrix is always symmetric?

Comment: @greenworld The definition of positive definitiveness for a matrix $A$ is given by the sign of the associated quadratic form $x^TAx$ and then the conclusion is quite general. Notably, since the  positive definiteness depends solely upon the symmetric part, of course we can have $A$ positive definite but not symmetric.

Comment: Ah yes, "recall" this fact! I totally recall this fact that nobody ever mentioned :-) +1

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes symmetry is required in the definition.  If one removes the symmetry requirement, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is positive definite, but not symmetric.

Comment: Its eigenvalues are complex numbers, so we cannot conclude that it is positive definite.

Comment: @greenworld Compute the quadratic form: $\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} = x^2 + y^2 \geq 0$. The eigenvalue characterization only applies to the [symmetric part of the matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/325412/169852).

Comment: So the definition in wiki page has a problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations
When they stated: "All its eigenvalues are positive". right?

Comment: @greenworld No, look at the first sentence in that section: "Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ **Hermitian** matrix." The property is true for a Hermitian (including symmetric) positive definite matrix.