# if $A+A^T$ is stable, then is $A$ also stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A+A^T$ has stable eigenvalues (their real part is strictly negative). I remember seeing somewhere that this involves that $A$ is also stable but I do not know exactly where and what ... Can someone help me?

It was an inequality, I recall, saying that the greatest eigenvalue of $A+A^T$ is greater than the greatest eigenvalue of $A$ or something like that ...

### Edit

use Lyapunov with $P= I$

Comment: $A+A^T$ is a symmetric real matrix and so its eigenvalues are real.

Comment: At least for a $2$-by-$2$ real matrix $A$, the stability of $A+A^\top$ implies that of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Proposition.**  For an $n$-by-$n$ real matrix $A$, if the matrix $A+A^\top$ is stable, then $A$ is stable.

Let $B:=-A$.  Write $S:=B+B^\top=-(A+A^\top)$.  Then, $A+A^\top$ is stable if and only if $S$ is positive-definite. We suppose that $A+A^\top$ is stable.

For a nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$2\,\left(v^\top\,B\,v\right)=v^\top\,B\,v+v^\top\,B\,v=v^\top \,B^\top \,v+v^\top\,B\,v=v^\top\,S\,v>0\,.$$
That is, $v^\top\,B\,v>0$ for every nonzero $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consequently, $B$ is a real positive-definite matrix (in a [broader sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Extension_for_non-symmetric_matrices)).  From [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues), the real part of every eigenvalue of $B$ is positive.  Therefore, the real part of every eigenvalue of $A=-B$ is negative.  This shows that $A$ is stable.

The converse does not hold.  As in achille hui's example (see [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues)), the eigenvalues of
$$A:=-\begin{bmatrix}3&7\\1&3\end{bmatrix}$$
are $-3+\sqrt{7}<0$ and $-3-\sqrt{7}<0$.  Thus, $A$ is stable.  However, the eigenvalues of
$$A+A^\top=-\begin{bmatrix}6&8\\8&6\end{bmatrix}$$
are $2>0$ and $-14<0$, whence $A+A^\top$ is not stable.