# Test definiteness of square real non-symmetric matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Assume a real square non-symmetric matrix $M$ is given and the task is to analyse if the matrix is positive definite, that is if $x^TMx>0$.

Is it possible to make assertions about definiteness by only checking the principle minors?

That means, the analysis should not necessarily include a consideration of the symmetric form $(M+M^T)/2$.

Comment: you need at least that all eigenvalues are positive

Comment: @Surb Definiteness is not characterised by eigenvalues in the non symmetric case: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83134/207930

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear how to adapt the usual [Sylverster's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) to non-symmetric matrices. For instance, consider the matrix
$$ M= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ b & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
where $a$ and $b$ will be fixed later. The principal minors are $1$ and $1-ab$. But for the symmetric matrix
$$ \frac{M+M^T}{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & (a+b)/2 \\ (a+b)/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
the principal minors are $1$ and $1-((a+b)/2)^2$.

This way, the map $x \mapsto x^t M x$ is positive definite if and only if $1-((a+b)/2)^2>0$. This is not something you can check only looking at $1-ab$. For instance, if $a=0, b=10$, then both $1$ and $1-ab$ are positive, but $x \mapsto x^T M x$ is not positive definite.

Comment: This is a really interesting example. I only found this paper of Fiedler and Ptak https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02166034 , though, I cannot find out so far the relation of positive definiteness and the principal minors.